# How to access a remote machine which is in a LAN

Tags: networking, remote-access, lan

I have a machine located at my office. It is in a LAN, and has a private IP address, something like 192.168.X.X, but it can connect to the Internet.

I also have another machine at my home. It share the Internet Connection through wireless, and it also has a private IP address, something like 192.168.x.x.

I want to access the remote machine at my office from my house. I think it is possible.

Give me some clues, I may be able to find it out.

Comment: You need to explain in more detail. Your question is ambiguous.

Comment: what kind of connection? Files or remote desktop? What OS (i'm assuming ubuntu considering where this was migrated from) and version?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up port forwarding on the modem or server which connects your office network to the Internet. This way, the modem/server will redirect all incoming connections from Internet to a certain port to an IP in your LAN - for external clients it'll look as if the service (SSH, for example) is running on the external IP of your modem.

Modern ADSL modems allow you to set up port forwarding via their web-based configuration tools.